# Asymptotics of 2-states Markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $\Phi$ be a discrete time Markov chain, with states $1$ and $2$, and transition probability matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}( 1 + \Theta ) & \frac{1}{2}( 1 - \Theta ) \\
\frac{1}{2}( 1 - \Theta ) & \frac{1}{2}( 1 + \Theta )
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $-1 \leq \Theta < 1$, $\Gamma(1)=a-b$ and $\Gamma(2)=a+b$, for some real constants $0 \leq b <a< \infty$.

The Markov chain $\Phi$ is irreducible and ergodic and its equilibrium distribution is symmetric,
so that the long-run probability of each state is $\frac12$.

Questions:

(1) Does there exist a real constant $\beta$ such that
$$G =\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ \prod_{j=1}^K \Gamma(\Phi_{t+j}) \right] \beta^{-K}$$ is strictly positive and finite.

(2) If the answer to (1) is yes, is $\beta$ unique?

(3) What, if any, is the relationship between $\beta$, $a$ and $b$?

My answer: (1) yes. (2) yes, $\beta$ is unique. 
(3) I believe that $a-b< \beta <a+b$.

What I don't see is any rigorous proof of (1) or (2) (even though both seem *obvious*). 
We know in the long-run, the Markov chain spends half its time in each state. 
Therefore, $$\mathbb{E}\left[ \prod_{j=1}^K \Gamma(\Phi_{t+j}) \right]$$ looks like it asymptotically behaves as $$\left[\sqrt{(a-b) (a+b)}\right]^K\ ?$$ Hence, a plausible guess is $$\beta = \sqrt{(a-b) (a+b)}$$ but I am inclined to think it is not quite true.

Both states are forever possible (i.e. neither is an absorbing state). Therefore, it seems $\beta$ cannot be less than $(a-b)$ or more than $(a+b)$ (else $G$ tends to infinity or zero respectively). 
How do I make my arguments rigorous?

If one works with not the product but the **sum**, I think one can argue, because of the ergodicity of the Markov chain, that $$\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{j=1}^K \Gamma(\Phi_{t+j}) \right] = \frac{1}{2}( a - b + a + b ) = a$$ 
but I am not sure if that is helpful for the question at hand.

Answer (score 6):

For a finite Markov chain $\Phi$ with transition matrix $q$, the behaviour of the expectations
$$
G_K=E\left(\prod_{j=1}^K\Gamma(\Phi_j)\right)
$$
when $K\to\infty$ is described by the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue $\rho_\Gamma$ of the matrix $q_\Gamma$ defined by
$$q_\Gamma(x,y)=q(x,y)\Gamma(y)$$ in the sense that $$\lim\,(G_K)^{1/K}=\rho_\Gamma$$
Thus, the only way $G_K/\beta^k$ can have a positive and finite limit is if
$$
\beta=\rho_\Gamma
$$
Now, the matrix $q_\Gamma$ is $$q_\Gamma=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}( 1 + \Theta )(a+b) & \frac{1}{2}( 1 - \Theta )(a-b) \\
\frac{1}{2}( 1 - \Theta )(a+b) & \frac{1}{2}( 1 + \Theta )(a-b)
\end{pmatrix}
$$ whose trace and determinant are $(1+\Theta)a$ and $\Theta(a^2-b^2)$ respectively hence $\rho_\Gamma$ is the largest root of the polynomial $$\rho^2-(1+\Theta)a\rho+\Theta(a^2-b^2)$$ that is, finally, $$\beta=\rho_\Gamma=\frac12\left((1+\Theta)a+\sqrt{(1-\Theta)^2a^2+4\Theta b^2}\right)$$

Comment: why does the central limit theorem apply to $N_K(1)$ ?

Comment: @mercio Because this is an additive functional of a Markov chain.

Comment: Thank you. I like the approach. Can I ask a few questions for clarification.

Comment: Ques 1: The CLT is justified (without iid) because all moments are bounded, right?

Comment: Ques 2: The almost sure convergence of $N_K(1)/K$ to $1/2$ is justified because all moments are finite (most textbooks assume iid but I know the SLLN is more general)? Question 3: The exchange of limit and expectation is justified by the Bounded Convergence Theorem, right?

Comment: Question 4: I am still completely lost on how you get the expression for $\sigma^2$? It is a text-book result to get the probability of going from (for example) state 1 at time $t$ to (for example) state 2 at time $t+j$ (or any other combination of states - just take powers of the transition probability matrix - the textbook by Ross has this in the exercises to Chapter 4). But how does one say anything about the distibution (eg variance) of $N_K(1)$?

Comment: It struck me that another way to get some of these results is by using the Perron-Frobenius Theorem (unfortunately, that is a tough theorem for me to get my head around)?

Comment: With that expression for $\sigma^2$, as $\Theta \rightarrow 1$, $\sigma^2 \rightarrow \infty$. That means the derived expression for $\beta$ might be greater than $(a+b)$? That surprises me? I also expected the expression for $\sigma^2$ to be symmetric as $\Theta$ tends to plus or minus one? (I am not saying the expression is wrong but it looks non-intuitive behaviour?)

Comment: Perron-Frobenius indeed readily yields the solution, please see revised answer.

Comment: Thank you for that. One question, please? Does that mean that one can write $\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} G_K = \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}[ \prod_{j=1}^K \Gamma(\Phi_{t+j}) ] = \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \beta^K = \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \rho_{\Gamma}^K$?

Comment: Or one cannot say that the ``constant of proportionality" is one? So, maybe $\lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} G_K = c  \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} \rho_{\Gamma}^K$, for some constant $c \in (0,\infty)$ which does not depend on $K$ (but $c$ need not equal unity).

Comment: The result is weaker, in the sense that one only knows that $\log G_K=K\log\rho_\Gamma+\epsilon_K$ with $\lim\epsilon_K/K=0$ while you are asking for $\lim\epsilon_K$ to exist and be finite. To spot the difference, imagine that $\epsilon_K=\sqrt{K}$, or that $\epsilon_K=-\sqrt{K}$.

Comment: Is it true that there is an inequality? 
Namely, there exist real constants $\underline{c}$ and $\overline{c}$ satisfying 
$0 < \underline{c} < \overline{c} < \infty$ such that 
$\underline{c} < \lim_{K \rightarrow \infty} ( G_K / \beta^K ) < \overline{c}$?

Based on my understanding of Horn and Johnson (1990, Corollary 8.1.33), 
$\underline{c}$ (respectively, $\overline{c}$) should (I think - and this is slight guess-work) equal the 
ratio of the minimum of the elements of the eigenvector of $q_{\Gamma}$

Comment: to the maximum of the elements of the eigenvector of $q_{\Gamma}$   
(respectively, the 
ratio of the maximum of the elements of the eigenvector of $q_{\Gamma}$ 
to the minimum of the elements of the eigenvector of $q_{\Gamma}$).
By (at least my understanding of) the Perron-Frobenius logic, all the elements of the eigenvector are strictly positive, so these ratios 
are not zero or infinity i.e. we must have $0 < \underline{c} < \overline{c} < \infty$?

Comment: If my reading is valid, there may be a somewhat related inequality, 
namely, for any $K \geq 1$, one has $0 < \underline{c} \beta^K < G_K < \overline{c} \beta^K$. 
Does that seem correct, please?